# Python List as variable name

Tags: python, arrays, list, variables, multidimensional-array

I've been playing with Python and I have this list that I need worked out. Basically I type a list of games into the multidimensional array and then for each one, it will make 3 variables based on that first entry.

Array that is made:

```
Applist = [
['Apple', 'red', 'circle'],
['Banana', 'yellow', 'abnormal'],
['Pear', 'green', 'abnormal']
]
```

For loop to assign each fruit a name, colour and shape.

```
for i in Applist:
    i[0] + "_n" = i[0]
    i[0] + "_c" = i[1]
    i[0] + "_s" = i[2]
```

When doing this though, I get a cannot assign to operator message. How do I combat this?

The expected result would be:

```
Apple_n == "Apple"
Apple_c == "red"
Apple_s == "circle"
```

Etc for each fruit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/4518341) covers dicts, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971967/4518341) covers named tuples.

Comment: @wjandrea - Your second link is a question asked 4 years after this one. Combining both does cover this but marking it as a duplicate when the second was asked 4 years after this one doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: [Older questions can be closed as duplicates of newer questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/343832)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bad idea. You should not dynamically create variable names, use a dictionary instead:

```
variables = {}
for name, colour, shape in Applist:
    variables[name + "_n"] = name
    variables[name + "_c"] = colour
    variables[name + "_s"] = shape
```

Now access them as `variables["Apple_n"]`, etc.

What you really want though, is perhaps a dict of dicts:

```
variables = {}
for name, colour, shape in Applist:
    variables[name] = {"name": name, "colour": colour, "shape": shape}

print "Apple shape: " + variables["Apple"]["shape"]
```

Or, perhaps even better, a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

variables = {}
Fruit = namedtuple("Fruit", ["name", "colour", "shape"])
for args in Applist:
    fruit = Fruit(*args)
    variables[fruit.name] = fruit

print "Apple shape: " + variables["Apple"].shape
```

You can't change the variables of each `Fruit` if you use a `namedtuple` though (i.e. no setting `variables["Apple"].colour` to `"green"`), so it is perhaps not a good solution, depending on the intended usage. If you like the `namedtuple` solution but want to change the variables, you can make it a full-blown `Fruit` class instead, which can be used as a drop-in replacement for the `namedtuple` `Fruit` in the above code.

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, colour, shape):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
        self.shape = shape
```

Comment: Thanks @lazyr, That was a very quick solution :) I just have one more question... if now you had for name, colour, shape in Applist: variables[name] = shape. Would that change the name in Applist, or would that create a new variable and not touch the Applist?

Comment: @Skowt `Applist` and `variables` are wholly independent after this code has run, and anything done to one of them will not affect the other.

Comment: Just thought I'd say thanks to @lazyr for answering my second questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to do this with a dictionary:

```
app_list = [
    ['Apple', 'red', 'circle'],
    ['Banana', 'yellow', 'abnormal'],
    ['Pear', 'green', 'abnormal']
]
app_keys = {}

for sub_list in app_list:
    app_keys["%s_n" % sub_list[0]] = sub_list[0]
    app_keys["%s_c" % sub_list[0]] = sub_list[1]
    app_keys["%s_s" % sub_list[0]] = sub_list[2]
```